# Configuring CentOS 6 iptables to use port 80 for NodeJS app running on port 3000

Tags: centos, iptables, centos6, node.js

I'm running a fresh instance of [CentOS 6](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NQAYLWO/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-5&qid=1442259308335) using AWS.  There is something in iptables that is blocking my nodejs app.

Here is my nodejs app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

By following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573737/269834), I tried to add an entry for my app with the following command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

When I run the node.js app and try to access it in my browser by going to `ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.YYY.compute.amazonaws.com`, my browser just hangs.

I have confirmed that iptables is not doing what I want it to do, because whenever I run the command `service iptables stop` and go to the address `ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.YYY.compute.amazonaws.com:3000` the app gets served.  However, I'm guessing it's not a good idea to not run iptables.

Node.js is running and listening, here is the output of `netstat -tulpn`:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1364/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               -
```

And here is what I get when I run the command `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to actually open up port 80 to the world too.

Full list of commands needed:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Do also remember to save the iptables config. This should be done with the following command:

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

You can also try and see if it is indeed iptables that are bugging you by opening up port 3000 in the firewall but still having it active:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: It must be something else that is doing something with port 80.  It still gets no connection when I run those 2 commands.  However, once I run `sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT` and then try on port 3000, the app loads.  How do I figure out what that something else is?

Comment: weird, it works now.  Sometimes I go to :80 and get nothing, then try :3000 and get something, then when I try :80 again, it seems to work.